# Arduino IDE cant find "#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>"

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to use NODMCU esp8266 lib in my project and it doesnt works

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE7uu.png)

the first lib is ok couse code just end run after it in second lib

I'm trying execute this code.
I've post image with code couse the stackoverflow doesnt reconize my code command

Comment: there is only one thing worse than a link to code, and that is a picture of code ... please edit your post, remove the link and paste the code, not picture of code

Comment: install the Blynk library

Answer (score -2):

BlynkSimpleEsp8266 is a separate sketch file,Which is not to found or to be found by installing the Blynk library,It is a different file which consists of different set of codes that can be written by you.
If that file exits or if exits in some other location make sure to add that to the location of the main file,and verify the spelling of it

Comment: the file is here in the Blynk library: https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-library/blob/master/src/BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h

Comment: and here is the official example https://examples.blynk.cc/?board=ESP8266&shield=ESP8266%20WiFi&example=GettingStarted%2FBlynkBlink